# Is there a way to correct rotation of a text based on a horizontal line?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, handwriting-recognition

I'm processing some images for OCR. But some inputs may be italic since they are handwriting. And sometimes this causes wrong results. I wonder is there a way to correct the rotation of these handwritten words based on this horizontal line below it?

Input:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Comment: I do not see how. The line is horizontal and the text is rotated. Why not get the rotated bounding box of the text using cv2.minAreaRect and just rotate  the text region using the angle provided.

Comment: is it right that the letters look upright, but the text direction is skewed (like stairs)?